# .savefig with geopandas results in empty figure

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas, savefig

I want to produce a plot of the canton of Zürich by by importing a shapefile of Switzerland (https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/geodata/landscape/boundaries3d.html) and zoom into the area of interest. In the last step I want to save the produced image as .eps file. The problem is that the save image file is empty.

First the packages geopandas and matplotlib are imported

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then the data of the shapefile is loaded

```
gdf = geopandas.read_file("swissBOUNDARIES3D_1_3_TLM_KANTONSGEBIET.shp")
```

Then the map of Switzerland is plotted. The canton of Zürich is colored different than all other cantons. After this, a zoom onto the canton of Zürich is done.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 18))
ax2 = gdf.plot(figsize=(30,18), edgecolor='black')
gdf[gdf.NAME == "Zürich"].plot(edgecolor='black', color='lightskyblue', ax=ax2)
gdf[gdf.NAME != "Zürich"].plot(edgecolor='black', color='aliceblue', ax=ax2)
plt.xlim(650000,750000)
plt.ylim(220000,290000)
```

The produced image should then be saved.

```
fig.savefig("filename2.eps", format='eps')
plt.show()
```

But the generated image is empty. It is also empty when the format is changed to png.

Answer (score 0):

The generated image is empty, because your plot is not on the correct figure. `gdf.plot()` creates a new figure. In order to save that figure you could remove the call to `plt.figure()` and get the figure from the axes with:

```
ax2.figure.savefig("filename2.eps", format='eps')
```

or create a subplot and pass the created axes as argument to the first `gdf.plot()`:

```
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,18))
gdf.plot(edgecolor='black', ax=ax2)
gdf[gdf.NAME == "Zürich"].plot(edgecolor='black', color='lightskyblue', ax=ax2)
gdf[gdf.NAME != "Zürich"].plot(edgecolor='black', color='aliceblue', ax=ax2)
plt.xlim(650000,750000)
plt.ylim(220000,290000)
fig.savefig("filename2.eps", format='eps')
```